# Future continuous to emphasize the duration of an action

Tags: future-tense, future-continuous

> This year he (fly) has flown over 60,000 miles for his job. He (work) has been working for Crossinglives & Co. for almost two years now. He (be) 
>   is sure sure that he (work) **will be working** for them next year as well

Why not say  will work instead of will be working to emphasize the duration?

Comment: You can use ***will work*** instead of ***will be working*** if you like. But note that neither version emphasises "duration" as such - it's just that ***will be working*** emphasises ***[unbroken] continuity***, so you might be less likely to use that version if your pilot always works for just three months a year. But this is just a matter of "likelihood, tendency", not a rule of grammar. If you want an easy life, just stick with ***will work***, because on average, *simpler is better*.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than duration, saying

> He is sure that he will work for them next year as well

has the sense of it being his choice to continue working with the company because of favourable job conditions, perhaps, or the certainty that his work was well received enough that he will still have a job with this company next year. In fact, by saying "next year", this emphasizes that the company hires people on a contractual basis, where the contract lasts a year.

On the other hand,

> He is sure that he will be working for them next year as well

only has the second sense of certainty that he will be rehired due to his admirable work so far.

To me, there is no question of change of duration between "will work" and "will be working" because the inclusion of  "next year" makes it clear that it is precisely for the following *one* year.